# stream reading with pyarrow results in module 'pyarrow' has no attribute 'StreamReader'

Tags: parquet, pyarrow

I'm trying to read a large parquet file using the pyarrow's stream reader as described [here](https://wesmckinney.com/blog/arrow-streaming-columnar/).
But I get the following error:

```
module 'pyarrow' has no attribute 'StreamReader'
```

I've tried switching to RecordBatchStreamReader but it seems its not made for reading Parquet files directly.

I'm using pyarrow 0.14.

Answer (score 1):

`RecordBatchStreamReader` is for reading the Arrow binary protocol, not for Parquet files. Try using `pyarrow.parquet.read_table`

http://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/parquet.html